# UI Automation Verify for finding AutomationId of elements

Tags: user-interface, ui-automation

I am trying to automate testing an application written in C++.
I use `UI Automation`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx
I used `UIAVerify` to find `automationIds` of some elements but some elements are showing as disabled(grayed-out) in the tool.

Does it mean interactions for some elements are not automatable? How to automate interaction for an element which does not have a `AutomationId` value?

**EDIT :** I am trying to use automation to click on a control that has `ControlType.Custom` and has `Name` property set for it. Is there a way to do this? I tried these two ways, both fail:

method 1:

```
//using framework white
var button = window.Get(SearchCriteria.ByControlType(ControlType.Custom).AndByText ("<Name Property>"));
```

method 2:

```
//using Automation Framework
aeCtrl = aeParentPanel.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children,
                            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "<Name Property>"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the ["How To Use UI Verify"](http://www.codeplex.com/Download?ProjectName=UIAutomationVerify&DownloadId=29576) Word .doc file that's linked to from the [UIA Verify](http://uiautomationverify.codeplex.com/) page on `codeplex`:

> **Note**   A dimmed (unavailable) node in the Automation Elements Tree indicates that the element is a member of the UI Automation Raw View but does not meet the conditions necessary to be considered a member of either the Content View or Control View. However, the element can still be tested from Visual UI Automation Verify. For more information, see the UI Automation Tree Overview.

What this basically means is that these elements are 'chrome' items, they are things like menu bars or scrollbars, rather than content such as list items. They are still there and can be tested.

--

Not every element has an `AutomationID`. It's really up to the developer to set these as appropriate for use in testing. In some cases, they come from the underlying framework: for example, for `Win32` controls, the `Control ID` - if present - is used to generate the `AutomationID`. In `WPF`, you have to set the deverloper has to assign it via the `AutomationProperties.AutomationId` Attached Property.

Typically its only set for controls in dialogs, and is used to distinguish between them. Items within a control - eg. items within a list box - are usually identified by their `Name` instead (or `Value`, for other controls). This is especially the case with items that are generated from an external source - such as a list containing filenames - since there's no reasonable way `AutomationIDs` could be assigned in advance there.

Comment: thanks for pointing to the word reference, I should've searched for that! I think I'll have use Name/Value properties for other controls. These 'Names' might change in next build of my product, so need to workaround ...

Comment: If it's your product, then you should be able to assign the AutomationID to something stable. The other main use for AutomationID is as a form of 'name' that is stable across localized builds - can't easily use Name there since it's going to be different on each language. What framework are you using - Win32, WinForms, WPF, or something else?

Comment: My product is written in C++. I think AutomationID can be assigned by developers if they are writing products in managed languages only. Can I still assign AutomationID ? thanks in advance.

Comment: All I  know is that it is written in C++, that makes it Win32 right?

Comment: It could be plain Win32 - using the USER32 controls directly - or could MFC. Either way, the AutomationID is based on the underlying control ID - usually the ID of the control in a dialog box template, which you can also get/set using GetWindowLong(GWL_ID) - check with whoever owns the code for details. If they're already using IDs and it's something stable, then likely you can use it for test. But if they are assigning the IDs dynamically at run time, you're out of luck. (If they're not using it, you might be able to coax them into setting it to values for test code to use...)

Comment: (...and note that these IDs only apply to overall HWNDs - so to a whole listbox or listview or tabstrip, but not to the individual list items or tab items within them - you have to use name or something else to tell those apart.)

Comment: For my application, I can access those elements which dont have automationID using 'Name' property on a Windows 7 machine. But even 'Name' access fails when I move to win2k3 machine. Undoable.

Comment: Elements dont seem to have same names, and many are without names!